# CSS how to keep span element fixed in progresbar

Tags: html, css

I am using the following CSS to display a progresbar and in it I display the time that is left. For some reason no matter what I try the displayed time wont stay at its place and is moving left as the proress bar width is decreasing. I have tried a lot of ways to keep the text from moving and keep it centered but none seems to work. Please help !

CSS:

```
.progress {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

.progress-value {
  
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 15px;
  
}
```

The div ( the div with the ID timer needs to be in the middle of the progres bar and it should not move while the progres bar is degreasing !)

```
<div class="progress">
<div id='progress' class="progress-value"><span id='timer' style="display: inline; width: 300px !important;"></span></div></center></div></center>
```

Comment: Hi I looked at your code, you can't a center element to center objects in the document. The progress bar is meant to move so not quite sure what you're trying to keep centered?

Comment: In the <span id='timer' style="display: inline; width: 300px !important;"></span> I have a time value 00:02:41 that counts down as well. That value I need to keep centered while the progress bar is moving. So in other words the span element should not move with the progres bar

Comment: In that case make sure the span is not inside the progress bar, create a div above and center an object there, but not with <center> tags. :)

Comment: Tried that to. Than it places itself before the progres bar, I need it to be in the middle of the progress bar, as if it was its background or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the progress bar and the time element in another div, position relative, then I can absolutely position the time element in any position; in this case I centered it in the div.

The time stays put because it's out of the flow of the document but it's div takes up the same space as the progress bar.

```css
.progress {
  background: rgba(5,5,5,0.5);
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border-radius: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-value {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 15px;
  width: 35%;
}

.progress-and-timer {
position: relative;
}

.timer-value {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-and-timer">
<div id="timer" class="timer-value">time</div>
<div class="progress">
<div id="progress" class="progress-value">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```